# Perl: How do I remove the first line of a file without reading and copying whole file

Tags: perl, line

I do have a whole bunch of files in a directory and from every file I want to remove the first line (including carriage return). I can read the whole file into an array of strings and write all but the first element to a new file, but that looks a bit cumbersome to me are there better ways? Oh the prefered language is Perl.

Comment: This is impossible because how files are stored. You will always have to read the entire file, and write everything but the first line - the OS has no other way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this one liner

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = "" if ( $. == 1 );' filename
```

I've used it before, should be all you need.

Comment: basically it says run perl, parse in place and execute the following line of code. The following line uses the default variable $_ which in this case is the line read in by the -p option. $. is the line number of filename. so if the line number is == 1 then set the text of the line to "".

Answer (score 11):

How about

```
tail +2
```

in shell?

(edit: in newer Linux you may need `tail -n +2` (thank you, GNU! :( ))

Answer (score 9):

```
perl -n -i -e 'print unless $. == 1' myfile
```

This is similar to stocherilac's answer.

But, in any case (and in all the others answer given!) you are always reading the full file. No way of avoiding that, AFAIK.

Comment: In Windows under MinGW console that one erased my file "Can't do inplace edit on myfile: Permission denied"

Answer (score 9):

> Oh the prefered language is Perl.

Sometimes `sed` is a better `sed` than even perl:

```
sed -i 1d *
```

Answer (score 5):

```
use Tie::File qw();
for my $filename (glob 'some_where/some_files*') {
    tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $filename or die "Could not open $filename: $!";
    shift @file;
}
```

Comment: Note that this still has to read and copy the whole file, but that's inherent in the problem.  I don't know of any OS that provides any other way to remove data from the beginning of a file.

Comment: Tie::File is my obvious choice because it's been explicitly written to deal with this exact problem category efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Schwern, the following does ***not*** perform an early exit as I had originally thought it would:

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = q// and last if $. == 1;' myFile
```

Seems like one *cannot* avoid processing the whole file after all.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.  If it did, it would violate how files work on Unix.  What's really happening is `$_ = ""` is always false so `$_ = "" and last` is the same as `0 and last`. It short circuits and never calls `last`. You have written: `perl -pi e '$_ = q// if $. == 1' myFile` which is a clever way to not print the first line, but it most definitely reads the whole file. Run with with `-MO=Deparse` to get the code and run it in the debugger to see.  `do { this; that; } if something` is a safer construct.

Comment: @Schwern : My bad. It took a while for your explanation to sink in, but I see your point.